# Returning server side class from a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I think this is an odd problem im having, I have a few class defined on the server side, which i then reference through a Service Reference, two of which are working as they should be. I have specified the known types from the services interface:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Obj))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(DigitalObject))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(AnalogueObject))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(AttributeType))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(AttributeData))]
```

From the silverlight application I then reference the class by:

```
private ServiceReference.AttributeData commonData = new ServiceReference.AttributeData();
```

This is working fine, however I am doing exactly the same thing with another class, the only difference is that the class named `AnalogueObject` and `DigitalObject` are derived from the class of type `Obj`. Do you have any idea what is going on? The namespaces are all the same, and I have rebuilt both the web solution and updated the service reference.

Example class:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CapCon2
{
    public class Obj : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
        private string _Description;  
        public string ID { get; set; }    
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _Description; }
            set
            {
                _Description = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }    
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}

    public class AttributeData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _Description;

    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Description 
    {
        get { return _Description; }
        set 
        {
            _Description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    public string Attribute { get; set; }

    public string DataType { get; set; }

    public string Input_InputSource { get; set; }

    public string Output_OutputDest { get; set; }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged!= null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error or problem? You aren't clear what the question is?

Comment: Sorry! The problem is that the class above 'Obj', can't be referenced from the silverlight project, and neither can the classes that derive from it. Two different classes can however, and I cant see any differenced between them..

Comment: Please share sample code from the one that works (`AttributeData`/`AttributeType`) for comparison

Comment: Hi, attributedata class has been included above.

Comment: Are you using the Obj type in any of the service methods (i.e. a method marked with OperationContract)? If not, the type will not be defined in the service definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to pass a complex type between the server and the client then you should mark it with the `DataContract` attribute and mark its properties with `DataMember`. This will tell .NET to serialize the object and pass it into the SOAP message.

Comment: Correct, but not exactly.  DataContract (and DataMember) helps define the types used in the service contract.  WCF will not include the type definition unless the type has been used in at least one of the service operations -- even if the type was marked with the DataContract attribute.